# Adding click event handler to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, addeventlistener

I want to handle `click` event on an `iframe` with a handler that gets the `iframe`’s id as parameter.

I’m able to add an `onClick` event handler via JavaScript as follows and it works fine:

```
iframe.document.addEventListener('click', clic, false);
```

But in this case I’m unable to pass a parameter to `clic()`. I tried to print `this.id` in `clic()` but no result.

`onClick` HTML attribute does not work at all, the handler is not called.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function def() {
    myFrame.document.designMode = 'on';
}
function clic(id) {
    alert(id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="def()">
<iframe id="myFrame" border="0" onClick="clic(this.id)"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Comment: as commented by [deepi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/787076/deepi) in an answer: `your code (what you gave on top) is working fine. But it's working when you click exactly on the border not in side box`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use closures to pass parameters:

```
iframe.document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {clic(this.id);}, false);
```

However, I recommend that you use a better approach to access your frame (I can only assume that you are using the DOM0 way of accessing frame windows by their name - something that is only kept around for backwards compatibility):

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").contentDocument.addEventListener(...);
```

Comment: thanks wladimir....u solved half of my prblm...but still this.id is nt working. if i pass "hello world" then it gets printed but for this.id it says "undefinied" in the alert box:S

Comment: Right, that's because you added the listener to the document - and the document doesn't have an ID. You probably want to add it to the `<iframe>` element instead, like in your first example: `document.getElementById("myFrame").addEventListener(...);`

Comment: Can you assign that event even when iframe is from different scope?

Comment: @FlashThunder: No, you generally cannot intercept clicks on frames from a different security context (if you could that would be a security issue).

Comment: there is no `.contentDocument` method for me. What am I missing?

Comment: @A.Savva: Could be a lot - like accessing something that isn't an `<iframe>` element or accessing a frame that didn't have a chance to load yet.

Answer (score 30):

iframe doesn't have onclick event but we can implement this by using iframe's onload event and javascript like this...

```
function iframeclick() {
document.getElementById("theiframe").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("theiframe").contentWindow.location.reload();
    }
}


<iframe id="theiframe" src="youriframe.html" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" onload="iframeclick()"></iframe>
```

I hope it will helpful to you....

Comment: it works only if the current website has the same protocol of the iframe (not working if one is http and the other one is https)

Comment: Defeats the purpose of using an iframe if this doesn't work across domains.

Comment: See 2 solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669523/984471