# [jQuery]Find click inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with an iframe.

```
<div id="my_content">
  <iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://mysite.com/iframe.html">
</div>
```

I need to intercept the click inside the iframe. I've tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#my_iframe').click(function(){ 
  alert('click inside iframe');
 });
});
```

Comment: I think jQuery code should be inside iframe. Then try to trigger something on iframe container.

Comment: You've searched for it? Seems there are alot of replies on it. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-onclick-event-to-iframe

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the iframe source is on the same domain as the outer page, you can use the [contents method](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#my_iframe').contents().click(function(){ 
    alert('click inside iframe');
  });
});
```

Comment: very very useful ! but do keep in mind that this snippet of code must be placed rite after the <iframe></iframe>

Comment: @atif, the above code can be placed anywhere within the page that contains the `iframe` - it needn't be directly after it.

Comment: well in my case it is not working if i place it in the heading of the page. Furthuremore, it needed me to refresh page once in order to make it working, so i added jQuery(window).load instead of document.ready

Comment: @atif, apologies. In my previous comment I meant anywhere within the body of the page that contains the iframe.

Comment: it is not working for me also.

Comment: Hi @KshitijVerma, can you post an example of your code that's not working (in another question) and I'll happily take a look; but the above code snippet will work (assuming that jQuery is loaded, the "#my_iframe" is a suitable locator for the iframe and the iframe source is on the same domain as the outer page.