# OnClick function doesnt fire on iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make click function fire when iframe is being clicked but It doesn't fire. Is it possible to do it ?

```
$("#iframe").click(function() {
alert("works");
});

<iframe id="iframe" src="http://site.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another solution is to overlay a transparent div and add a click event to that div.
Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/AxJHH/

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe src="#url"></iframe>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

css to position the div.overlay over the iframe:

```
.container{position:relative;float:left;}
.overlay{top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;}
```

Add the event:

```
$('.overlay').click(function(){alert('hello');});
```

Comment: But then you can't interact with the iframe :(

Comment: if you're only looking for the initial click, you can remove the overlay programmatically afterwards

Comment: great!! working

Answer (score 5):

```
$iframe = $( document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.document );

$iframe.find("body").click(function(){
    alert("hey");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cRDjV/81/

Comment: This will only work on authorized sub domains or the same domain, not if the iframe refers do a diffrent domain

Comment: hopefully yes :- ) 
 he can only use your overlay solution if iframe differ in domain

Comment: It works, just not with `alert()` inside the anonymous function. Try redirecting the event call to a global function.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to do this inside the iFrame, rather than the parent.

You could however, add an EventListener: [Adding click event handler to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-onclick-event-to-iframe)

Comment: Not totally impossible in some cases to create a script outside the function.