# IFrameElement EventListener not being called

Tags: dart, flutter-web

I have added an EventListener to an IFrameElement, but it is never being called.

Listener definition:

```
  EventListener eventListener = (e) {
    print("Lisenter clicked.");
  };
```

IFrameElement definition:

```
  var type = 'click';

  IFrameElement element = IFrameElement()
    ..width = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 400).toString()
    ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString()
    ..srcdoc = value
    ..addEventListener(type, eventListener)
    ..style.border = 'none';

  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      createdViewId,
          (int viewId) => element);
```

dispatchEvent definition:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));console.log("woot");});
```

"woot" is found in console when a marker is clicked, but I never see "Listener clicked". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Apparently a mouse click event doesn't work for cross domain iframe. There is a solution in the form of Gist here. https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598

You can try this. In my small test mouseOver event worked properly. But I couldn't recreact the click event. 

There are other references in stackoverflow aimed at this issue. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792953/onclick-function-doesnt-fire-on-iframe

Comment: Following way of adding event listeners could help with the clarity of listeners on your element

`element.onMouseLeave.listen((evt) {
              mouseOver = false;
              print('Mosue is leaving iframe');
            });`

Comment: Will try these out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
    "marker.addListener('click', function() {dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));"
        "var o = Object.create(null);"
        "o.id = \"${property.id}\";"
        ""
        "console.log(o);"
        "window.parent.postMessage(o);"
        ""
        "});\n";
```

Then I attach a listener on the window:

```
window.onMessage.listen((onData) {
  // do things
  if (messageEvent.data["id"] == property.id) { }
})
```