# onclick handler not working in case of iframe in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have this iframe where I embedded a youtube video but the issue is that onclick handler does not work on this iframe.
Another issue is that I want to write something on the iframe but that does not seem to be happening even if we insert a header inside iframe.
Here is the code that i  have .
The code is in reactjs .

```
<div onClick={this.onClick} className="movieItem">
                <iframe width="400" height="300" src={youtubeVideoUrl}>

               </iframe>
               <span className="title"> {movie.EventTitle}</span>
              </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add click event to a iframe with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: 1. You aren't setting an `onClick` prop on `<iframe />`, which is just as well since iframes do not directly support click handlers (there are some workarounds, but probably not what you're after). 2. iframes do not render child nodes.

Comment: Check out this answer, it will accomplish what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16793204/1064310

Comment: you not have access to onClick iframe

Answer (score 0):

I have used react-iframe and useEffect hook. Find the element where you want to use click event and add it.

```
import Iframe from "react-iframe";
 
useEffect(() => {
    $('#pdf').on('load', function() {
     $('#pdf').contents().find("body").find('#slider').click(function(){
        console.log('work fine');
     });
   }
 }, []);
 
 return (
    <>  
      <Iframe
        url="localhost:3000"
        id="pdf"
      />
    </>
 );
```