# Javascript - Detect is user is subscribed to youtube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I use Youtube subscribe button (https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button ).

Is there any way, while user clicks on it, to initiate my javascript function too?

Comment: Interesting. Just to be clear, you've seen the Ts&Cs section? "You may not offer or promote prizes or rewards of any kind in exchange for clicking on a YouTube Subscribe button." We had a lot of questions a while ago where people wanted to gate access to a website on whether users had clicked 'like this on Facebook' but I haven't seen a YouTube version before!

Comment: how come [toneden.io](https://toneden.io) are doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a data element with the function that you need to run.

```
<script>
function myEvent(e) 
{ 
    // do something here 
}
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-onytevent="myEvent"></div>
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button#Handling_Events_Demo

Comment: The Subscribe Button's subscribe and unsubscribe events have been deprecated. Similarly, the `data-ytonevent` attribute, which could previously be added to the widget element to specify a listener for event notifications, has also been deprecated. — [source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference)

Answer (score 1):

just put the name of your function in an onclick like so:

```
<div id="whatever they make you call it" onclick="yourFunction();" />
```

or do this in javascript

```
document.getElementById("whatever it's called").onclick = "yourFunction();";
```

I'm not saying it's a good idea, and it will probably violate their terms of use, but this is what I would try.

Comment: The actual button is rendered inside an iframe inside the div, though. IIRC the click event won't be passed up to the div from that - although it looks like it's possible to [find the iframe and register a click handler on its content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6452502).