# Javascript onclick method in ArcGIS iframe is disappearing

Tags: javascript, iframe, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, esri-arc-engine

I'm using ESRI's ArcGIS Web App to create a map that has several interactive features.  By clicking on specific objects in my map, users will see a pop up (created using the Web App creation features) with information about the area they clicked on.

Some of those pop ups contain a link that should open up a new window to display an image (that I have hosted on my web server).

Here's where my problem begins.  In the map builder, inside my ArcGIS online login where I set everything up, I have added the link control to the configured popups that tells it to use Javascript in an "onclick" to tell it to open a new window, of a specific size, and where to find the image to display.  It all works fine in the builder.  But as soon as I create the web app, it completely drops my "onclick".

And more-so, I tried to work around this by changing the href of the link to "javascript:myScriptHereTellingItToOpenANewWindow" and the web app then drops the "javascript:" part and changes it to "#" thus still not working when I click it, all it does is try to open a new browser tab and ignores the rest of the script written in the href.

I'm sorry I have to be somewhat vague because this is for a company project that has high security.  Below is what little code I can share (cleaned up a little to hide confidential information).

In the ArcGIS Web Map builder, here is the code I have in my configured popup:

```
<a onclick="window.open('URL of image file I want to load','width=1000,height=202,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_parent">View Featured Line</a>
```

And as I said, that works fine in the editor.  But once I chose to "Create a Web App from this map" it drops the "onclick" completely.

If I put it in the href tag, like below:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('URL of image file I want to load','width=1000,height=202,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_parent">View Featured Line</a>
```

Then when I "inspect source" in the web app, it looks like this (which doesn't work either):

```
<a href="#window.open('URL of image file I want to load','width=1000,height=202,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_parent">View Featured Line</a>
```

Comment: The onclick is missing in the files that the builder generates?

Comment: This might help for the iframe issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe