# Adding on click events to IFrame which opens a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently developing a div that will contain up to 4 *Media* type divs.  The media types include images, PDFs, and Youtube videos. 
 The code I currently have running creates the divs as imgs if possible. If it is not possible(youtube videos/pdfs) it opens them as IFrames. 
 As of now, the user is able to click on the imgs which launches a modal. However, I am unable to to get the IFrames to show the modal.
Here is my code
  HTML - Modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="mediaModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <p>here would be the description</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-media">  
       <p>here is the media</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <p>here would be the credits
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascirpt

```
//this creates img/iframes dynamcially and throws them into a media-container div
var source = null;
    //if it is not a youtube video/pdf/txt, put it in a img tag
    if( null == ( media[1].match(/pdf/i) || media[1].match(/txt/i) || media[1].match(/youtube.com/) ) )
    {
       source = "<img data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mediaModal' id='m" + i + "'src='"+ media[1] + "'<img>";
    }
    else //throw it in a iframe tag
    {
       source = "<iframe data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mediaModal' class='modz' id='m" + i + "'src='"+ media[1] + "'></iframe>";
    }
    var div = $(source);
$("#media-container").append(div);
```

I tried adding a class to the iFrame and adding an onClick method, but it does not seem like the IFrame is picking up a click.

```
  //opens a modal box for IFrame media.
  $(".modz").on("click", function(e){
     console.log("BING");
     $("#mediaModal").modal('show');
  });
```

Any help would be awesome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer by folowing the step in this answer: 
[stackoverflow.com adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe/6452637#64526372)